# Asynchronous playback of several <img> tags with same animated GIF

Tags: javascript, html, browser, asynchronous, animated-gif

I have a lot of `<img>` tags on one HTML page some of whom share the same animated GIF file. The `src` URL is set dynamically by JavaScript but with my code the same characters are either played all again or following characters are immediately displayed with the last frame.

**The idea:** This is for an art project. After some text has been entered the characters are displayed in a special font and some transition is done *character per character* (one after another) which I can only realize by using animated GIFs. The text is split into single characters and `<img>` tags are created like this:

```
<!-- delivered HTML at page load -->
<img src="initial/f.png"> <!-- I used to PNG here to outline -->
<img src="initial/o.png"> <!-- the animation is NOT set a first -->
<img src="initial/o.png">
```

When the animation starts the first `<img>`'s URL is set to `transition/f.gif`. Only after it has finished playing (determined by time) the 2nd image is set etc.

```
<!-- while 2nd animation is running -->
<img src="transition/f.gif"> <!-- already finished, displays last frame -->
<img src="transition/o.gif"> <!-- being animated right now -->
<img src="transition/o.png"> <!-- will be reset to o.gif in next step -->
```

**The problem I can't solve:** After `o.gif` from the example has been played the animation of the next O doesn't work correctly.

I tried defining a class for every character and assigning the image as `background-image`. Once any occurrence of a character had played any following occurrences of the same letter displayed the last frame (end state) of that GIF immediately when displayed.

I also tried setting the `src` attribute directly with JavaScript but when the 2nd letter O is set like this the first letter O's animation restarts synchronously. But it shall stay at the last frame.

As the HTML page should also work on the local filesystem I think arguments like `o.gif?random=argument` for bypassing cache mechanism won't work or won't have any effect (maybe on some computers, testing on my own won't falsify).

Comment: "a special font and some transition is done character per character (one after another) which I can only realize by using animated GIFs" - I'm sure you can do this using something else, e.g. canvas, especially if it's for an art project and you therefore probably don't care about browser support

Comment: Wide browser support is no must-have but always good. The animations are created by the artist herself who cannot write code. Due to time and budget restrictions we'll definitely stick to GIF files. Easy for here to create and me to use (besides this issue).

Comment: I hate to recommend the internet's skeliton in the closet, but have you considered Flash?  Easy to learn, easier to animate in then most GIF animators, and you have full control over sync and timing.

Comment: Funny paraphrase for "Flash":-) Well, I never learned Flash and refuse to do for a little art project. When I had the first meeting with the artist I also mentioned Flash and even she as a non-techie forcefully rejected it. So to say, yes, we considered Flash but don't want to use it. Is that GIF problem a common issue?

Comment: Not really, there are several javascript plugins that have at least some sort of frame by frame control over GIFs, but none of them look like they'd be easy to reverse engineer.  You're going to be learning **something** new for just this one project, I'd suggest building your own super-simple Javascript animator.  Have it load some images into an array, and cycle through them using `setTimeout()`.  You'll get full control over everything that way!

Comment: Threw together a quick example of a Javascript animator in an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create unique urls for the images, so the browser will always reload letters instead of using the cached ones.
You could achieve this for example with a small php, which is outputting the correct gif for a parameter.

```
<img src="gif_printer.php?letter=o&t=1234567">
```

The t parameter should be the timestamp when you create the img tag. This gives enough difference to redownload.

In the php set headers to limit/disable caching and output type to gif, and simply pour the contents of the image to stdout.

The timestamp parameter and the cache-control headers should be enough for the browser to redownload evert letter.

If your test environment is not reacting correct, you could try htaccess solution, but for that you have to use a web server (and this could already be enough for the previous solution to work).

That means rewrite any url to images/[a-z].gif into images/[a-z].gif, so simply remove additional noise except the first letter and the extension.

Comment: I'd already need a HTTP server for using the PHP [or any other scripting language] script. What benefit do you expect from using a rewrite rule in a `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Well, I tested referencing `o.gif?pos=LETTER_INDEX` with local files and surprisingly it works. I take it it will also work on HTTP because the browser can't know they are actually the same file. Because one can obviously use the `?` syntax with any file there is no need for a HTTP server (for local files) or a scripting language (for web serving). Of course it would be much better to solve the actual problem than using "different" files -- So I'll keep this open some time and look for other answers.

Comment: The problems cause to my knowledge is, that the browser sync's same files, and so you have to tweak it to think of the same letters, as different ones. I also keep an eye open, to learn about this further.

Answer (score 2):

Consider not using GIFs, but image sequences and Javascript.  I've thrown together a rough instantiable Javascript object that does just that:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function Animator(target, frames, delay)
            {
                var _this = this;
                // array of frames (image objects)
                var f = [];
                // a reference to the object where our frames will appear
                var t = document.getElementById(target);
                // the interval variable.  Used to stop and start
                var t_loop;
                // create a new image element and remember it
                var img_el = document.createElement("img");
                // current frame
                var c_frame = 0;

                t.innerHTML = "";
                t.appendChild(img_el);

                var i, img;

                // preload immediately
                for(i = 0; i < frames.length; i++)
                {
                    img = new Image();
                    img.src = frames[i];
                    f.push(img);
                }

                this.play = function()
                {
                    t_loop = window.setInterval(_this.frame, delay);
                }

                this.stop = function()
                {
                    clearInterval(t_loop);
                }

                this.gotoFrame = function(frame)
                {
                    c_frame = frame;
                    _this.frame();
                }

                this.frame = function()
                {
                    img_el.src = f[c_frame].src;

                    c_frame++;

                    if(c_frame >= f.length)
                    {
                        c_frame = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            function loaded()
            {
                var quip_frames = [
                    "http://www.abcteach.com/images/abma_thumb.gif",
                    "http://www.abcteach.com/images/abcu_thumb.gif",
                    "http://www.abcteach.com/images/zbma_thumb.gif",
                    "http://www.abcteach.com/images/zbcu_thumb.gif",
                    "http://www.abcteach.com/images/dnma_thumb.gif",
                    "http://www.abcteach.com/images/dncu_thumb.gif"
                ];

                var anim1 = new Animator("target1", quip_frames, 100);

                var anim2 = new Animator("target2", quip_frames, 100);

                var anim3 = new Animator("target3", quip_frames, 100);

                anim1.play();
                window.setTimeout(anim2.play, 200);
                window.setTimeout(anim3.play, 300);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="loaded()">
        <div id="target1">
        </div>
        <div id="target2">
        </div>
        <div id="target3">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*thanks to [ABCTeach](http://www.abcteach.com/font_details.php) for the images*

The object loads the images in a loop, stores them in an array, then through simple use of `setInterval()` swaps out frames at a desired rate.  When the page loads it makes three of these objects, each pointing to a different DIV, but each with the same frames.  It then tells each to play with a different delay (the first one immediately, the second after 200ms, the third after 300ms).  In your case you'd make one array for every letter you'd use:

```
var A = [*array of URLs to images of the letter A*];
var B = [*array of URLs to images of the letter B*];    
...
```

Then create a new `Animator` object for every div on your page, sending it the appropriate letter array:

```
var letter_so_and_so = new Animator("div_so_and_so", A, 100);
var letter_this_and_that = new Animator("div_this_and_that", B, 100);
var another_letter = new Animator("another_div", B, 100);
```

Finally give each one either an offset start, or call their `Animator.gotoFrame(f)` method to start them on different frames (don't forget to `Animator.play()`!).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PacmanBits/WCJ2e/)

Try to adopt something like this into your code, I think you'll find it works wonders.